# Get class object pointer from inside a static method called directly

Tags: c++, gcc, cortex-m

I have the following class, for example in a header:

```
class Uart
  {
  public:
    Uart (int ch, int bd = 9600, bool doinit = false);
    ......
    static void isr (void);
   }
```

The idea is this class represents USART hardware, the same way as SPI, RTC etc and I set the address of static member *isr* as interrupt vector routine during runtime.
For example like this

```
extern "C"
{
  void
  Uart::isr (void)
  {
    if ( USART1->SR & USART_SR_RXNE) //receive
      {
    short c = USART2->DR;
    USART1->DR = c;
    USART1->SR &= ~USART_SR_RXNE;
    ;
      }
    else if ( USART1->SR & USART_SR_TC) //transfer
      {
    USART1->SR &= ~USART_SR_TC;
      }
  }
}
```

And set it as a interrupt vector, for example

```
_vectors_[USART1_IRQn + IRQ0_EX] = (word) &dbgout.isr;
```

So each time this "callback" routine is called by CPU I want to get access to it's "parent" object to save and/or manipulate the received data in userfriendly manner.
Is it possible at all? Maybe somehow organize the class or whatever.
The architecture is strictly 32bit (ARM, gcc)

Comment: 1. What "parent" object? Am invocation of a static member function is by definition *not* associated with any particular object. Can you be clearer on what you mean? 2. A static member function cannot have C language linkage, the `extern "C"` does nothing for you here.

Comment: You'll have to use a non-member function plus whatever technique you decide to use to associate data with a callback instance when the callback API didn't include a parameter for arbitrary data

Comment: Thank you a lot! I mean is it possible to get address of Uart class or in any case I have to declare it as global variable? Sorry I'm still new to C++. Or as static member in most cases are inline it's not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static methods know nothing about the object.

You need a different approach:

```
// Create interrupt handler method (non-static!)
void Uart::inthandler() {
    // whatever is needed here
}

// Create object
Uart* p = new Uart(...);

// Create interrupt handler function
void inthandler() {
    if (p != NULL) {
        p->inthandler();
    }
}

// Install the interrupt handler function
InstallIntHandler(IRQ, inthandler);
```

It's just a principle that has to be adapted to your specific environment.

Comment: BTW, it looks like static member can access another static fields of the same class. So if I create static pointer to THIS in the constructor, I will be able to access it from interrupt without any external helpers/global wariables

Comment: Yes, you are right. The only problem of static data members is that you cannot use multiple objects to handle multiple UARTs.

Comment: Yes, but as the number of UARTs are limited, I can create corresponding number of handlers, like isr1, isr2 and assign it to *main* isr in the constructor. Not a big deal, I think.